# How to POST using -x in VBA HTTP API

Tags: vba, ms-access, curl

I have a bunch of API calls to STRIPE which are working well.
Generally I use the cURL version and work out what I need to do.

I have just come across the need to DELETE a subscription:

```
   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_FpZkRarex4obNX \
  -u sk_test_VHkTM0bOtpsE1dBnTxFbMBAk00WnBQnyI5: \
  -X DELETE
```

The issue is I have no idea how to use the -x in VBA

My current code for other calls is:

```
api_Key = getStripeAPI

req = "DELETE"

Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpReq.Open "POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/" & stripeSubID, False

httpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & api_Key
httpReq.send req
strResponse = httpReq.responseText
Debug.Print strResponse
writeToText strResponse
Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
```

I know the above code is incorrect but if someone can let me know how to utilise -X that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using it, just passing the wrong argument. It's the first argument to `.Open`:

```
httpReq.Open "DELETE", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/" & stripeSubID, False
```

Answer (score 1):

ok wow i just figured it by myself.. after 45 mins of trying.

For those looking fr this:

-x DELETE means use DELETE as the "GET"/"POST" option.

working code:

```
api_Key = getStripeAPI



Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpReq.Open "DELETE", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/" & stripeSubID, False

httpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & api_Key
httpReq.send
strResponse = httpReq.responseText
Debug.Print strResponse
writeToText strResponse
Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
```